# Difference between using ctx.bumps and passing in the bump

Tags: solana-program, bump

There is two ways of ensuring the bump

**First:** Client side passed as parameter to be stored program side

```
const [pubkey, bump] = findProgramAddress()

program.methods.myMethod({bump})
```

**Second:** Solana progam side using

```
let bump = ctx.bumps.get("some_str")
```

I was wondering, does anyone know if there are any difference between using either method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second approach is a feature provided by Anchor that eliminates the need to find and pass the bump for a PDA from the client-side. It also ensures you get the correct bump for the PDA.

Previously, I think the first approach was not recommended because it allowed passing in non-canonical bumps. A "canonical bump" is the first bump found that results in a valid PDA. However, I believe Anchor now enforces the use of canonical bumps with the `seeds` and `bump` constraints, so this may no longer be an issue. In any case, the second option is simpler.

Here is a sec3 article that explains how bumps work with PDAs: https://www.sec3.dev/blog/pda-bump-seeds